# Installing Phonegap on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I am completely stuck.

I have tried using the guide on http://www.jakenovak.com/installing-phonegap-on-ubuntu-13-10-with-local-android-package-building/

Then I tried using the latest ppa via:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties python g++ make
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

but whatever I attempt to install phone gap via

```
sudo npm install -g phonegap
or
sudo npm install -gf phonegap
```

I get the error:

```
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap/-/phonegap-3.3.0-0.19.5.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap/-/phonegap-3.3.0-0.19.5.tgz
npm ERR! TypeError: Arguments to path.resolve must be strings
npm ERR!     at Object.exports.resolve (path.js:313:15)
npm ERR!     at Object.exports.relative (path.js:370:20)
```

This seems like an npm error but I am not sure how to resolve it.

Any help would be very welcome.

Thanks,

Fido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I managed to figure this out. It was a duplication error on my part. I had two versions of npm installed. Version 1.1 etc which kept producing the error, when I switched to the correct version 1.3.24 this error resolved itself. I am guessing that simply upgrading npm resolves this issue.